# Issue with json in python

Tags: python, json

Trying to get a json object but having issues. Over a socket a device is sending me the following:

```
b'device json string:[\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TV1-5100",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Receiver",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "5100",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 2\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.8",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 1,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPD5100-5A070AC4E24B",\r\n\t\t"txName" : ""\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TV2-5100",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Receiver",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "5100",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 2\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.3",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 2,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPD5100-9A7A201CE92F",\r\n\t\t"txName" : ""\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TV4-5100",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Receiver",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "5100",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 2\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.4",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 4,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPD5100-C6D6B6467C22",\r\n\t\t"txName" : ""\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TV3-5100",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Receiver",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "5100",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 2\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.11",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 3,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPD5100-CAC95249B11C",\r\n\t\t"txName" : ""\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TV2",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Receiver",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "",\r\n\t\t"online" : false,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 2,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPD6000W-341B22F004C0",\r\n\t\t"txName" : ""\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TV1",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Receiver",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "",\r\n\t\t"online" : false,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 1,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPD6000W-341B22F00502",\r\n\t\t"txName" : ""\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "S2",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Transmitter",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.9",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 4,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPE5100-341B22F00532"\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "S3",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Transmitter",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.5",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 1,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPE5100-8ACBD04FAB3F"\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "S1",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Transmitter",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.6",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 3,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPE5100-BABB87D44C6A"\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "S4",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Transmitter",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.13",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 2,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPE5100-CE17116E0D56"\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TBA2",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Transmitter",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "",\r\n\t\t"nameoverlap" : true,\r\n\t\t"online" : false,\r\n\t\t"previewurl" : "http://10.0.0.100/customization/previewImage.jpg",\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 5,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPE6000W-341B22F00496"\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "BRIGHT1",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Transmitter",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "",\r\n\t\t"nameoverlap" : true,\r\n\t\t"online" : false,\r\n\t\t"previewurl" : "http://10.0.0.100/customization/previewImage.jpg",\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 6,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPE6000W-341B22F00499"\r\n\t}\r\n]\r\n\r\n\r\n'
```

This is a byte string and if i use .decode() or not i'll still get error when using json.loads(data)

```
data = data.decode()
js = json.loads(data)
```

This will give me:

```
in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

If I print data after decode it comes out like this. Note the device json string: is part of the string

```
device json string:[
        {
                "aliasName" : "TV1-5100",
                "deviceType" : "Receiver",
                "group" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "5100",
                                "sequence" : 2
                        }
                ],
                "ip" : "10.0.0.8",
                "online" : true,
                "sequence" : 1,
                "service" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "telnet",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "ssh",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "http",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "https",
                                "status" : true
                        }
                ],
                "trueName" : "IPD5100-5A070AC4E24B",
                "txName" : ""
        },
        {
                "aliasName" : "TV2-5100",
                "deviceType" : "Receiver",
                "group" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "5100",
                                "sequence" : 2
                        }
                ],
                "ip" : "10.0.0.3",
                "online" : true,
                "sequence" : 2,
                "service" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "telnet",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "ssh",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "http",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "https",
                                "status" : true
                        }
                ],
                "trueName" : "IPD5100-9A7A201CE92F",
                "txName" : ""
        },
        {
                "aliasName" : "TV4-5100",
                "deviceType" : "Receiver",
                "group" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "5100",
                                "sequence" : 2
                        }
                ],
                "ip" : "10.0.0.4",
                "online" : true,
                "sequence" : 4,
                "service" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "telnet",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "ssh",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "http",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "https",
                                "status" : true
                        }
                ],
                "trueName" : "IPD5100-C6D6B6467C22",
                "txName" : ""
        },
        {
                "aliasName" : "TV3-5100",
                "deviceType" : "Receiver",
                "group" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "5100",
                                "sequence" : 2
                        }
                ],
                "ip" : "10.0.0.11",
                "online" : true,
                "sequence" : 3,
                "service" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "telnet",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "ssh",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "http",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "https",
                                "status" : true
                        }
                ],
                "trueName" : "IPD5100-CAC95249B11C",
                "txName" : ""
        },
        {
                "aliasName" : "TV2",
                "deviceType" : "Receiver",
                "group" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "ungrouped",
                                "sequence" : 1
                        }
                ],
                "ip" : "",
                "online" : false,
                "sequence" : 2,
                "service" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "telnet",
                                "status" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "ssh",
                                "status" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "http",
                                "status" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "https",
                                "status" : false
                        }
                ],
                "trueName" : "IPD6000W-341B22F004C0",
                "txName" : ""
        },
        {
                "aliasName" : "TV1",
                "deviceType" : "Receiver",
                "group" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "ungrouped",
                                "sequence" : 1
                        }
                ],
                "ip" : "",
                "online" : false,
                "sequence" : 1,
                "service" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "telnet",
                                "status" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "ssh",
                                "status" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "http",
                                "status" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "https",
                                "status" : false
                        }
                ],
                "trueName" : "IPD6000W-341B22F00502",
                "txName" : ""
        },
        {
                "aliasName" : "S2",
                "deviceType" : "Transmitter",
                "group" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "ungrouped",
                                "sequence" : 1
                        }
                ],
                "ip" : "10.0.0.9",
                "online" : true,
                "sequence" : 4,
                "service" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "telnet",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "ssh",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "http",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "https",
                                "status" : true
                        }
                ],
                "trueName" : "IPE5100-341B22F00532"
        },
        {
                "aliasName" : "S3",
                "deviceType" : "Transmitter",
                "group" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "ungrouped",
                                "sequence" : 1
                        }
                ],
                "ip" : "10.0.0.5",
                "online" : true,
                "sequence" : 1,
                "service" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "telnet",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "ssh",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "http",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "https",
                                "status" : true
                        }
                ],
                "trueName" : "IPE5100-8ACBD04FAB3F"
        },
        {
                "aliasName" : "S1",
                "deviceType" : "Transmitter",
                "group" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "ungrouped",
                                "sequence" : 1
                        }
                ],
                "ip" : "10.0.0.6",
                "online" : true,
                "sequence" : 3,
                "service" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "telnet",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "ssh",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "http",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "https",
                                "status" : true
                        }
                ],
                "trueName" : "IPE5100-BABB87D44C6A"
        },
        {
                "aliasName" : "S4",
                "deviceType" : "Transmitter",
                "group" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "ungrouped",
                                "sequence" : 1
                        }
                ],
                "ip" : "10.0.0.13",
                "online" : true,
                "sequence" : 2,
                "service" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "telnet",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "ssh",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "http",
                                "status" : true
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "https",
                                "status" : true
                        }
                ],
                "trueName" : "IPE5100-CE17116E0D56"
        },
        {
                "aliasName" : "TBA2",
                "deviceType" : "Transmitter",
                "group" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "ungrouped",
                                "sequence" : 1
                        }
                ],
                "ip" : "",
                "nameoverlap" : true,
                "online" : false,
                "previewurl" : "http://10.0.0.100/customization/previewImage.jpg",
                "sequence" : 5,
                "service" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "telnet",
                                "status" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "ssh",
                                "status" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "http",
                                "status" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "https",
                                "status" : false
                        }
                ],
                "trueName" : "IPE6000W-341B22F00496"
        },
        {
                "aliasName" : "BRIGHT1",
                "deviceType" : "Transmitter",
                "group" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "ungrouped",
                                "sequence" : 1
                        }
                ],
                "ip" : "",
                "nameoverlap" : true,
                "online" : false,
                "previewurl" : "http://10.0.0.100/customization/previewImage.jpg",
                "sequence" : 6,
                "service" : [
                        {
                                "name" : "telnet",
                                "status" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "ssh",
                                "status" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "http",
                                "status" : false
                        },
                        {
                                "name" : "https",
                                "status" : false
                        }
                ],
                "trueName" : "IPE6000W-341B22F00499"
        }
]
```

My first time posting so formatting might be wrong.

Comment: You need to remove `device json string:`. That's not JSON.

Comment: @ti7 Wrapping it in `{}` won't fix it, since `device json string` also needs to be in quotes. Just remove it.

Comment: @Barmar ahah - right as usual; edited

Comment: @ti7 Yes thank you that was the problem. I had a feeling just should have tried to remove it first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you can remove the `device json string:` at the start of the bytes data, before loading it with `json.loads`.

Also, it might be slightly more efficient to simply do split operations using a `bytes` object instead of a `str`, as shown below.

```py
import json

b = b'device json string:[\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TV1-5100",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Receiver",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "5100",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 2\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.8",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 1,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPD5100-5A070AC4E24B",\r\n\t\t"txName" : ""\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TV2-5100",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Receiver",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "5100",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 2\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.3",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 2,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPD5100-9A7A201CE92F",\r\n\t\t"txName" : ""\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TV4-5100",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Receiver",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "5100",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 2\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.4",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 4,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPD5100-C6D6B6467C22",\r\n\t\t"txName" : ""\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TV3-5100",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Receiver",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "5100",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 2\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.11",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 3,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPD5100-CAC95249B11C",\r\n\t\t"txName" : ""\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TV2",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Receiver",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "",\r\n\t\t"online" : false,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 2,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPD6000W-341B22F004C0",\r\n\t\t"txName" : ""\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TV1",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Receiver",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "",\r\n\t\t"online" : false,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 1,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPD6000W-341B22F00502",\r\n\t\t"txName" : ""\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "S2",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Transmitter",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.9",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 4,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPE5100-341B22F00532"\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "S3",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Transmitter",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.5",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 1,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPE5100-8ACBD04FAB3F"\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "S1",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Transmitter",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.6",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 3,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPE5100-BABB87D44C6A"\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "S4",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Transmitter",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "10.0.0.13",\r\n\t\t"online" : true,\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 2,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : true\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPE5100-CE17116E0D56"\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "TBA2",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Transmitter",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "",\r\n\t\t"nameoverlap" : true,\r\n\t\t"online" : false,\r\n\t\t"previewurl" : "http://10.0.0.100/customization/previewImage.jpg",\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 5,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPE6000W-341B22F00496"\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t"aliasName" : "BRIGHT1",\r\n\t\t"deviceType" : "Transmitter",\r\n\t\t"group" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ungrouped",\r\n\t\t\t\t"sequence" : 1\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"ip" : "",\r\n\t\t"nameoverlap" : true,\r\n\t\t"online" : false,\r\n\t\t"previewurl" : "http://10.0.0.100/customization/previewImage.jpg",\r\n\t\t"sequence" : 6,\r\n\t\t"service" : [\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "telnet",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "ssh",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "http",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t"name" : "https",\r\n\t\t\t\t"status" : false\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t],\r\n\t\t"trueName" : "IPE6000W-341B22F00499"\r\n\t}\r\n]\r\n\r\n\r\n'

header_len = len('device json string:')  # header_len == 19

js = json.loads(b[header_len:])
print(js)
```

Out:

```py
[{'aliasName': 'TV1-5100', 'deviceType': 'Receiver', ...}]
```